# How do I convert two DataFrame columns into summed Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
              date  sku  qty
0       2015-10-30  ABC    1
1       2015-10-30  DEF    1
2       2015-10-30  ABC    2
3       2015-10-31  DEF    1
4       2015-10-31  ABC    1
...            ...  ...  ...
```

How can extract all of the data for a particular `sku` and sum up the `qty` by date. For example, the `ABC` SKU?

```
2015-10-30   3
2015-10-31   1
       ... ...
```

The closest I've gotten is a hierarchal grouping with `sales.groupby(['date', 'sku']).sum()`.

Comment: This sounds right. Is there any issue with this grouping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will work with all (or several) `sku`, then:

```
agg_df = df.groupby(['sku','date']).qty.sum()

# extract some sku data
agg_df.loc['ABC']
```

Output:

```
date
2015-10-30    3
2015-10-31    1
Name: qty, dtype: int64
```

If you only care for `ABC` particularly, then it's better to filter it first

```
df[df['sku'].eq('ABC')].groupby('date')['qty'].sum()
```

The output would be the same as above.

Comment: That was perfect, tyvm.